# A driver (service) for this device has been disabled. Is how the code 32 starts off:

Tags: windows-7, drivers

A driver (service) for this device has been disabled.  An alternate driver may be providing this functionality. (Code 32)

No drive letter show in device manager, and the DVD/CD drive is unusable because it couldn't be seen. This all happened, when I starting using a new, external USB hard drive from Buffalo. I have Win-7 64bit. Everything else looks to be working fine.

I even tried to hook up, and external DVD that had worked fine in the past. Just too slow and ate up memory, so I never used it. It tries to use the same drives, and when you click to update drivers, it says this is the best one.

Even if I want to use the factory win 7 re-installation DVD, How could I? I've got no drive to install it from *in this situation*. I am lost here, and Buffalo tech was of no help at all. Just said that he could not help.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have this same problem with my USB drivers on Windows 8.  They were working fine then I rebooted for some updates and now I can't get them to work.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the Device Manager Code 32 error is probably correct.  There may be a driver or service that is missing which is preventing Windows from accessing your DVD/CD drive.  These drivers are often referenced as Upper or Lower Filters. I find this to be a common problem after installing or uninstalling software related to CD/DVD drives (e.g. DVD burning software).  What often has happened is that a driver is referenced in the Windows Registry but the file doesn't exist.

Here's how to check for Upper or Lower filters that are interfering with the proper function of your CD/DVD drive (adapted from [these instructions on about.com](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/driverssupport/ht/upperfilters-lowerfilters.htm)):

1. Click on the **Start** button.

   - If you're using Windows XP, also click on **Run**.
2. In the *Search programs and files* box (Windows 7 and Windows Vista) or the *Run* textbox (Windows XP) type **regedit** and click **OK** or press the **ENTER** key.

   - This will open the Registry Editor program.
   - Important: Changes to the registry are made in these steps. Take care in making only the changes outlined below. While it's not a necessary step to complete this process, I recommend that you play it safe by backing up the registry keys you're modifying.
3. Locate the **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE** folder under *Computer/My Computer* and click the **|>** or (**+**) icon next to the folder name to expand the folder.
4. Continue to expand folders until you reach the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class` registry key.
5. Click on the **|>** or (**+**) icon next to the **Class** key to expand it. You should see a long list of subkeys open up under **Class** that look something like this: **{4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}**.
6. Click the registry subkey **{4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}**
7. In the results that appear on the window on the right, locate the **UpperFilters** and **LowerFilters** values.

   - Note: If you only see one or the other value, that's fine.  Just skip the one that's missing.
8. **Right-click** on **UpperFilters** and choose **Rename**.  Add "**-BAD**" to the end so the entry is named `UpperFilters-BAD`
9. Repeat step 8 with the **LowerFilters** value.
10. Close Registry Editor and restart your computer.
11. Check to see if renaming the **UpperFilters** and/or **LowerFilters** registry values solved your problem.
12. If this did **not** solve you problem, repeat steps 8 and 9 above to return the **UpperFilters** and **LowerFilters** values to their original names (without "-BAD" at the end).

It may be necessary to reinstall any programs designed to utilize the device you've removed the **UpperFilters** and **LowerFilters** values for. For example you may have to reinstall your DVD burning software.